# Tamanho máximo do texto da consulta sql

Tags: sql, string, query

Qual é o tamanho máximo de uma string de consulta sql?
(maximum query statement)
Ex:

```
SELECT * FROM ajuda WHERE (id = 1 OR id = 2 OR id = 3 OR...
```

@edit:

O banco que eu estava utilizando (access) possui outros limites além dos sitados pelo @PauloHDSouza.

- Number of characters in an SQL statement
- Number of AND operators in a WHERE or HAVING clause
- Number of characters for a parameter in a parameter query

Comment: Tamanho máximo do comando?

Comment: creio que não haja um limite para o comando porém como você esta usando `OR` quando a query encontrar algum que retorne `true` ele para de executar.

Comment: ja tentou WHERE id in(1,2,3,4,5) ????

Comment: Ah não sei exatamente o que pretendes, mas seria bom se editasses a pergunta e tentasses ser um bocadinho mais claro.

Comment: O @PauloHDSouza respondeu o que eu queria. Não fui claro porque queria saber do geral de banco de dados mesmo. Em inglês a pergunta faria mais sentido já que não consigo pensar em uma tradução para: maximum query statement.

Comment: O tamanho máximo vai depender do seu processador para a query. Pois a SQL é ilimitada.

Answer (score 2):

Olá,

O valor em KB é

**65,536 * Network Packet Size**

Network Packet Size você configura no seu servidor SQL

[image: Network Packet Size]

Fonte:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx

Comment: Bom, não fui claro quanto as especificações do banco e driver de conexão. Mas este não era o intuito. Sua resposta é o que eu queria saber mesmo.